# resizing a web page horizontally

Tags: html, scroll

How can I make the layout of my web page not disturb when its re-sized horizontally. Just like when its re-sized vertically, scroll bar appear. How that could be done for horizontal re-sizing. Just like how stackoverflow behaves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to wrap your page (and content) in a 'container'. This container can then be given a fixed width. This means everything within this container can be positioned relative to the container itself, but the pages content will never exceed the boundaries of the container you've set.

This can be done by setting the `width: 800px` in your stylesheet. An example of this is described [here.](http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/css/css-tricks.shtml)

Once setup it means your pages layout set within the container will not alter if the browser window has been resized. Due to you explicitly stating the dimensions of the container.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly... you want to give your content a fixed width (as opposed to a % width).  The "content" div of stackoverflow has the following CSS declaration:

```
margin: 0 auto;
min-height:450px;
width:960px;
```

So you can see that the width is set to always be 960px wide.  No matter how much the user resizes the browser horizontally, the width will always be 960px.  It will not expand or contract.

The margin is set to 0px top and bottom, and 'auto' for left and right (the notation you see there is shorthand for margin: 0 auto 0 auto, as the margin properties are declared clockwise from top... so: top, right, bottom, left).  The 'auto' for left and right result in the content div being centered.

Answer (score 0):

Use `overflow-x: auto;` for horizontal scrolling.